# How to add input(text) value into the href attribute of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been having a problen that's been bothering for the past couple of hours. I have a search input where after the user enters the input and presses send, the text should be added into the href attribute and sent to the results page where it will be used to query the database. I can't figure out a way to get it to work and if I could get help from any of you it would be really appreciated. I know how to get the search to work using ajax or just using ordinary html form so please don't suggest that. I just need it to work the way I asked, it's a long story :-). Thanks in advance. Here's an excerpt

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-text" placeholder="Search...">
<a href="results.php?search=WHERE-I-WANT-THE-INPUT-TO-GO" class="btn btn-default" id="send">Search</a>
```

Comment: Might need more info (like the code for your `<form>`) but you should probably set it up as a form with `method='get'` and `action='newurl'` rather than mess with jquery or javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### update

```
$("#search-text").on("keyup",function(e){
  if(e. keyCode === 13){
    var address = $('#send').attr('href');
    window.location = address;
  } 

  $('#send').attr("href","results.php?search="+$(this).val());
})
```

---

You can do something like this

```
$('#send').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var address = $(this).attr('href') + $('#search-text').val();
  window.location = address;
});
```

Provided the href looks like

```
<a href="results.php?" ... />
```

---

Improving @toby's solution a bit. Instead of `keypress` use `keyup`

```
$("#search-text").on("keyup",function(){
  $('#send').attr("href","results.php?search="+$(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works when I click the button but for some reason it's doesn't when I press enter after I enter whatever it is I want to search for. Any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 2):

```
var $anchor = $("#send");
$("#search-text").on("keypress",function(){
    $anchor.attr("href","results.php?search="+$(this).val());
})
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Is there any particular reason why ``$anchor`` must be global?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works when I click the button but for some reason it's doesn't when I press enter after I enter whatever it is I want to search for. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: @Leroy is doesn't work because what you have there is a hyperlink what you need if you want to press enter is a submit button, or add a event listener to the document in which you search for the enter keypress